# Using if-then else in CI/CD pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm currently trying to build a CI/CD Pipeline that runs in gitlab. I want to build a pipeline where gitlab can check whether the folder `node_module` is already inside the folder `WebClient`, if it isn't then execute job `deploy_node_module`, and if there is any changes in the folder `WebClient` then I will execute the job `deploy_dev_client`.

Currently, my gitlab-ci.yml is as followed:

```
    deploy_node_module:
      stage: client
      tags:
        - my tags
      script:
        - '& cd WebClient'
        - powershell.exe -NoP -NonI -Command "Expand-Archive -Path node_modules.zip -DestinationPath ..\WebClient"
      rules:
        - exists:
          - node_modules
          when: never

    deploy_dev_client:
      stage: client
      tags:
        - my tags
      script:
        - '& cd WebClient'
        - 'npm rebuild node-sass'
        - 'npm install @angular/cli@7.0.3'
        - '& npm run build-release --max_old_space_size=$NODE_MEMORY_SIZE'

      rules:
        - changes:
          - WebClient/*
          when: always
        - when: on_success
```

My goal for the pipeline is to after every push request:
1. Check whether there is `node_module` inside `WebClient`
2. Check whether there are any changes in any file in `WebClient` folder -> run job if true

I have attempted to use **if, then** in gitlab-ci.yml, however it did not went through, even though no syntax error was found when I tested on CI Lint:

```
deploy_dev_client:
  stage: client
  tags:
    - my tags
  script:
    - '& cd WebClient'
    - >
      if not exist node_modules;
        then powershell.exe -NoP -NonI -Command "Expand-Archive -Path node_modules.zip -DestinationPath ..\WebClient";
      else echo existing node_modules; 
      fi
    - 'npm rebuild node-sass'
    - 'npm install @angular/cli@7.0.3'
    - '& npm run build-release --max_old_space_size=$NODE_MEMORY_SIZE'

  rules:
    - changes:
      - WebClient/*
      when: always
    - when: on_success
```